# Navigate UIView to UINavigationViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIView` and I need to switch to `UINavigationController`.  This is the code I am using to navigate:

```
MainMenuNavigationViewController * aMainMenuNavigationViewController = [[MainMenuNavigationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuNavigationViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:aMainMenuNavigationViewController animated:YES];
```

I am getting an error

> -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "MainMenuNavigationViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

I wasted around 12 hours searching the internet. However I could not find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainMenuNavigationViewController.xib open in Interface builder, In document window right click on view referencing outlet was not set, so right click and select files owner view. That was the issue there. Now code that you shared isn't loading viewController using navigation Controller you are presenting MainMenuNavigationViewController modally presentModalViewController.

Comment: Thanks for answering I tried right clicking the Uinavigationviewcontroller and adding a referingoutlet however I still i am getting error.  Then I tried the refering outlet for navigation bar then I got no error but I am getting the navigation bar extended the whole screen.  Then I tried for View inside the Navigation controller but I was not able to assign to files owner.